# How to install Samsung scx printer driver from cd?

Tags: 10.10, printing

I tried to install from the CD the driver of my printer, a Samsung Scx-3200.

How can I install the printer driver?

Answer (score 1):

You can download the Unified Printer Driver from Samsung's official website. [This forum thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=341621) is the best guide for doing so.

Comment: I've edited your answer to include that, but [it would be considered *even better*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) if you were to summarize the important points in your answer as well (still providing the link for reference).

Answer (score 0):

Probably you will not find a Linux driver on the CD.
Ubuntu 11.10 and higher however include the Splix driver that works with your printer and it should get automatically set up.